# radeditor issue with safari

Tags: asp.net, webforms, safari, radeditor

i have a radeditor in my webform and it posts back. if i type any thing in the editor and press enter key for new line and then use any control in the page which reloads the page, then the next line character in the editor gets replaced by $0 and other text remains same as earlier. it happens in SAFARI.

Ex. 
aasdads

dsdsds

***the above text replaced by:***   aasdads$0dsdsds$0

plz suggest something..

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with this browser bug and it is fixed in the latest version of RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q2 2010. You can verify this in the live demos of RadEditor, for example: [Save In Database](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/saveindatabase/defaultcs.aspx) .